# JavaScript - module object syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I seem to have messed up some brackets, commas, semi-colons. They are highlighted as incorrect in Emacs. I assume that's why it doesn't work. I seem to have gotten lost in the curly braces, commas and semi-colons. I commented which parts are highlighed in red indicating syntax errors.

```
var myGallery = (function () {
    var s;

    return {

        settings: {
            data: JSON.parse(data),
        filter: document.getElementById("filter"),
        gallery: document.getElementById("gallery")
        },

        init: function() {
            // kick things off
            s = this.settings;
        // By default, call the fillImages function with 'all' tag
        this.createFilters("all");
        },
        createFilters: function(tag) {
        // Load the image data
        // I made imgs global as I couldn't access it from displayImg
        imgs = this.settings.data.images;

        // Get image tags and generate a tag array
        var tags = ["all"];

        for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(imgs).length; i++) {
        // Check if a tag is already in tags
        if (tags.indexOf(imgs[i].tag) > -1) {
            // Yes, it is, so don't add it
        } else {
            // No, it isn't, so add it to 'tags'
            tags.push(imgs[i].tag);
        }
        }
        // Create an unordered list, assign a class to it and append to filter
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.classList.add("ul-bare");
        this.settings.filter.appendChild(ul);


        // Iterate over the array and append each element as li
        for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var li=document.createElement('li');
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.innerHTML=tags[i];
        li.onclick = (function(x){
            return function() {
            this.displayImg(tags[x]);
            })(i);    // the first ) is highlighted in red
        }
    }, // both the curly brace and the comma are highlighed in red

    displayImg: function(filter) {
        // Add images to #gallery
        for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(imgs).length; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("img");
        // If the tage is 'all', display all images
        if (filter === "all") {
            div.src = imgs[i].src;
            this.settings.gallery.appendChild(div);
        } else {
            // Display only images of certain category (tag argument)
            if (imgs[i].tag === filter) {
            div.src = imgs[i].src;
            this.settings.gallery.appendChild(div);
            } 

        }
        }

        }
    }; // the semi colon is highlighted in red
}());

myGallery.init();
```

EDIT:
It seems that everything comes down to my closure. Once I've commented out this part, everything is ok:

```
//li.onclick = (function(x){
//    return function() {
//  this.displayImg(tags[x]);
//    })(i);
```

Edit 2:

So I've got the following:

```
li.onclick = (function(x) {
        return function() {
        console.log(tags[x]);
        this.displayImg(tags[x]);
        };
    })(i);
```

This works exactly as intended if I only want to print tags[x], however if I add the second statement this.displayImg...., then I get the error that this.displayImg is not a function.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your debugger say anything?

Comment: No, Chrome console does not throw any errors.

Comment: You're missing a curly brace.  I think the closing brace for your return statement is actually being considered the one for your IIFE.  Change the second to last line from `}());` to `}}());` and then run a formatter to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work unfortunately. I've added more details at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if your code was properly indented.

Comment: Use `M-x find-unbalanced parenthese` in Emacs, it should help you.

Comment: DizzyEgg - is it possible to do it on this website. The code is properly indented in Emacs. When I paste it here, it gets messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ...

li.onclick = (function(x){
    return (function() {
        this.displayImg(tags[x]);
    })
})(i);

// ...
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The closure still doesn't work but at least it stopped highlighting errors.

Comment: Hi Breck. I've added more details above

Comment: I'm going to create a new question because my original question here has been answered.